# Zariski's Main theorem

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Sir,

I am studying Zariski's Main theorem. May i know good source of problems related to Zariski's main theorem to understand it better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crossposted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34836/zariskis-main-theorem

Comment: I've voted to close. The question is not precise is enough, no background is given, etc.

Comment: Does "problems" mean "textbook exercises" or "research problems"?

Comment: The standard proof that formally etale + finite presentation actually implies etale is one example of Zariski's Main Theorem being used in commutative algebra.

Comment: Let F be a projective family over a normal, connected base. If a general fiber is equidimensional, then every fiber is equidimensional.

Comment: the best discussion of ZMT I know of is mumford's chapter at the end of his red book, or the even better discussion in his unpublished red book part 2.

Comment: Gack! I meant for the family to be flat, of course.